# Google Groups Settings API Update

Tags: google-groups

I'm trying to update the settings for a Google group.  I have an Oauth2 token but when I execute the following code:

```
Groupssettings mygs = buildGS();
Groups.Update hisgs = mygs.new Groups().update("11_sp_abd_000_01", gSettings);
hisgs.setOauthToken(token);
hisgs.buildHttpRequest();
hisgs.execute();

public static Groupssettings buildGS()
{
    return new Groupssettings.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, null)
    .setApplicationName("ApplicationName")
    .build();
}
```

I receive the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
com.google.api.services.groupssettings.Groupssettings$Groups$Update.set(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V

at com.google.api.services.groupssettings.Groupssettings$Groups$Update.<init>(Groupssettings.java:363)
at com.google.api.services.groupssettings.Groupssettings$Groups.update(Groupssettings.java:351)
at GetAuth.main(GetAuth.java:62)
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Evidently there was a conflict in Maven between the definitions in my POM file and my classpath.  I had 2 references to the com.google.api.blah.blah.Groupssettings class which was confusing Eclipse.  To resolve I removed the classpath reference to the jar file and left the POM reference et Viola!